# Can not load js file from mongo prompt

Tags: mongodb

I used to load js file from mongo prompt using command `load("test.js")`. But, since yesterday, I started getting Network Error as follows:

```
2020-02-14T21:35:06.156+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] [test.js:6:8] Error: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host '127.0.0.1:27017'
Stack trace:
@test.js:6:8
@(shell):1:1
----------
2020-02-14T21:35:06.156+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: error loading js file: test.js @(shell):1:1
```

I still could not figure it out, where the problem is, any help appreciated.

Comment: The mongo shell calls `isMaster` whenever it establishes a connection to a replica set.  Does test.js try to create a new connection?

Comment: Yes, It tries to establish a connection using following code: 'conn = new Mongo();
db = conn.getDB("testDB");'

Comment: My database is located in a single server without any replication.                                     > db.adminCommand( { replSetGetStatus: 1 } );
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "not running with --replSet",
        "code" : 76,
        "codeName" : "NoReplicationEnabled"
}
>

Comment: it is a "network error" while connecting to "127.0.0.1:27017" - is the mongod process running on localhost?

Comment: Yes, I got single server for both application and database. Now, it has started accepting connection and the problem is solved. Thanks.